# BIDS 2008 - Lookup value in source against two columns in lookup table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

Have a dataflow task where I need to lookup a value in a table that could exist in one of two columns.  Im not sure how to configure the lookup to do this.  Ive only used one value in the past.

If I was just using tsql, I would use a case statement and join on the lookup table, with the result being the matched value.

In other words, 
CASE WHEN source.column_a = lookup.column_a THEN lookup.column_a WHEN source.column_a = lookup.column_b THEN lookup.column_b END

How do i implement the above logic in the lookup transform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a union as the source in the lookup transformation, then use a single transform:

```
SELECT id, column_a FROM dbo.Table
UNION SELECT id, column_b from dbo.Table
```

Conversely, you can use two lookups with the first looking at column_a and pass the no match output to a second lookup with column_b, then union the results.